# Angular Directive - Keydown event does not update attached input in Unit Test

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine, angular-directive

I am writing unit tests for a Directive that simply prevents typing specific keys.
The directive works in the UI as expected, however, in the unit test, the simulated event is being fired but the input the directive is attached to is not being updated.

Directive:

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, HostListener, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appInputLimiter]',
})
export class InputLimiterDirective {
  @Input('pool') appInputLimiterPool?: string;
  constructor(public elementRef: ElementRef) {}

  @HostListener('keydown', ['$event']) onKeydownHandler(event: KeyboardEvent) {
    console.log(event
    if (this.appInputLimiterPool) {
      return this.appInputLimiterPool.includes(event.key);
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

TestComponent:

```
@Component({
  template: `<input type="text" appInputLimiter [pool]="0123456789" />`,
})
class TestComponent {}
```

Unit Test:

```
import { Component, DebugElement } from '@angular/core';
import { ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { By } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { InputLimiterDirective } from './input-limiter.directive';

@Component({
  template: `<input type="text" appInputLimiter pool="0123456789" />`,
})
class TestComponent {}

describe('InputLimiterDirective', () => {
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<TestComponent>;
  let inputDebugElement: DebugElement;
  let input: HTMLInputElement;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [InputLimiterDirective, TestComponent],
    });
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TestComponent);
    inputDebugElement = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('input'));
    input = inputDebugElement.nativeElement;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('Input element should be created', () => {
    fixture.detectChanges();
    expect(input).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it(`Should be able to type a character that is in the pool of allowed characters`, () => {
    let event = new KeyboardEvent('keydown', {
      key: '5',
    });
    inputDebugElement.triggerEventHandler('keydown', event);
    fixture.detectChanges();
    // FAILS: Expected 0 to equal 1.
    expect(input.value.length).toEqual(1);
    // FAILS: Expected '' to equal '5'.
    expect(input.value).toEqual('5');
  });
});
```

NOTE:

1. The call to `console.log(event);` in the directive does fire when the test is run and the logged `event` is correct and as expected, the only difference is that the `event`'s property `isTrusted` is `false`, this is expected.
2. When running the app, the component behaves as expected and typing characters that are in the 'pool' of allowed characters is successful.
3. Given the above I am sure that the Directive is functioning correctly, I believe that the problem is somewhere with the unit test or the behaviour of the component in the `TestBed`.

Comment: I think you should get new reference to nativeElement each time you call detectChanges rather than keeping initial reference inside beforeEach

Comment: @opel - thanks for sharing, I tried as you suggested however it made no difference. That said I have managed to successfully test the `paste` event whilst holding on to the same reference assigned in the beforeEach block.