How to unit test a keyDown directive on input with Angular?
I tried many variations based on answers here but none worked, the KeyboardEvent never sets value on the input.
How can I simulate a user typing characters?
Unit test:
@Component({
  selector: 'app-test-container',
  template: `
  <div>
    <label for="integerValue">Integer Value</label>
    <input id="integerValue" type="text" class="form-control"
      formControlName="IntegerValue" appOnlyInteger>
  </div>
  `
})
class MyComponent {}

fdescribe('IntegerOnlyDirective', () => {
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<MyComponent>;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [MyComponent, IntegerOnlyDirective],
    }).compileComponents();

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MyComponent);
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should accept integer as is', async () => {
    fixture.detectChanges();
    await fixture.whenStable();
    const inputElement: HTMLInputElement =
      fixture.debugElement.nativeElement.querySelector('input[type=text]');

    inputElement.dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent('keydown', { key: '1' }));

    fixture.detectChanges();
    expect(inputElement.value).toBe('1'); // FAILS -> value is ''
  });
});

Directive
@Directive({
  selector: '[appOnlyInteger]'
})
export class IntegerOnlyDirective {
    constructor(private el: ElementRef) { }

    @HostListener('input', ['$event']) onKeyDown(event) {
      const initialValue = this.el.nativeElement.value as string;

      // Will only keep the positive integers because any other character than digit is ignored
      // g for global, to catch all matches
      this.el.nativeElement.value = initialValue.replace(/\D*/g, '');
    }
}


Unlike https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69336661/angular-directive-keydown-event-does-not-update-attached-input-in-unit-test my directive does not even get called, difference is my directive is @HostListener('input', ['$event']) onKeyDown(event) and not @HostListener('keydown', ['$event']) onKeydownHandler(event). Is there any preferred between the two? I could not find any best practice for this

The browser may be blocking this.  Untrusted?: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/isTrusted

@browsermator I run the test in the console with jest
